# Searching for exact whole words in Pandas Dataframe from a List

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I know this issue has been asked a million times but I am still having challenges with it. I have a list of exact whole words I want to search in a pandas dataframe.

Counties_List = ['MOMBASA' ,'KWALE' ,'LAMU']

```
df2 = df1[df1['County/ Sub-County'].str.contains('|'.join(Counties_List))]
```

The code above partially works as it brings other rows that I dont need such as LAMU-NORTH etc. So I did a regex search for one item in the list eg LAMU only and the code worked as I expected. How do I map the rest all list items so that they can appear in df2. I would want a dataframe that has the exact whole words I included in the list.

```
df2[df2['County/ Sub-County'].str.contains('^LAMU$')]
```

Comment: `df2[df2['County/ Sub-County'].eq('LAMU')]`?

Comment: Why don't you include the anchors in the first code line? `df1[df1['County/ Sub-County'].str.contains(r'^(?:{})$'.format('|'.join(Counties_List)))]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. I was doing something close to what you just did but I decided to not post it here because I was afraid of embarrassing myself. I am still a beginner with regards to python for data science.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want an exact match of the items in `Countries_List` in your `Countey/ Sub-County` column. You may use

```
 df2 = df1[df1['County/ Sub-County'].str.contains(r'^(?:{})$'.format('|'.join(Counties_List)))]
 df2 = df1[df1['County/ Sub-County'].str.contains(rf'^(?:{"|".join(Counties_List)})$')] # Python 3.7+
```

Add `(?i)` before `^` to enable case insensitive matching.

Or, if you need a fixed string comparison, just use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df2 = df1[df1['County/ Sub-County'].isin(Counties_List)]
```

The regex that will result from `Counties_List = ['MOMBASA' ,'KWALE' ,'LAMU']` list will look like `^(?:MOMBASA|KWALE|LAMU)$`. The non-capturing group, `(?:...)`, will make sure the anchors are applied to all alternatives in the group.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h3S2WP/1).